# Browsing location to save and name while exporting PPT Slide as PDF in SlideShow Mode

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to save only 1 particular slide as .PDF (or image at the very least) whilst in SlideShow mode.

I want to give the user the option to browse the location and pick the name using the default browse feature. I don't want them to write the path.

```
    Dim ExportPath As String   ' drive:\path to export to
    Dim Pixwidth As Integer    '  size in pixels of exported image
    Dim Pixheight As Integer
    Dim oSlide As Slide

    ' Edit to suit
    Pixwidth = 1920    '  arbitrarily ... set whatever value you like here

    ' Set height proportional to slide height
    Pixheight = 1080

    ExportPath = ActivePresentation.Path & "\"

    Set oSlide = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide
    With oSlide
        .Export ExportPath & "Slide" & CStr(.SlideIndex) & ".JPG", "JPG", Pixwidth, Pixheight
    End With
```

I found the code in the web and it works well but doesn't allow the user to browse the location and choose the name.

I then used the following code which worked wonderfully:

```
Dim CurrentSlide As Long
CurrentSlide = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.SlideNumber
With ActivePresentation.PrintOptions
OutputType = ppPrintOutputSlides
End With

ActivePresentation.PrintOut
```

However, this doesn't work in all devices.
In some, it just doesn't recognize the `PrintOut` function and in others it gets printed in OneNote.

Is it possible for the user to browse and save as .PDF file (export option instead of Print option in case they don't have the PDF Printer)

Thank you.

Comment: Stick with `.Export`, check out this link for an explanation of using a FileDialog (aka default browse) to select a file location to save to: https://software-solutions-online.com/vba-save-file-dialog-filedialogmsofiledialogsaveas/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Show
Dim Location As String
Location = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).SelectedItems(1)
```

You can use the above code to get the path and name which the user desires.

This code will allow you to export: [ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.exportasfixedformat)